# Pass and restore a session id in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, sessionid

First, yes i know this is a big security **NONO**. But the scenario is this;

In the checkout of a webshop i use a payment-gateway, which can proxy my checkout form through their SSL.

(following url's is just the theory, other urls apply for the application)

The way it works, website redirects user to their **https**://gateway.org/secure-tunnel.php passing a url in the query like this ?url=http://myshop.com/cc-form.php <- needs to be urlencoded.

The secure-tunnel requests the url - sprinkle some magic on url in the document - and shows it to the user.

Now i want to pass the session ID to the cc-form.php url, and got that part working. BUT the requested page don't pick up the session ID that is passed.

Any ideas on that?

The following is from my application.ini

```
resources.session.name = UPSSESSID
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
resources.session.use_only_cookies = off
resources.session.referer_check = off
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
```

Also while researching i found that the Suoshin extension could be causing some problems, so i have added this to the .htaccess

```
php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
```

I use a route to my payment form

```
$this->_helper->url->url(array(session_name() => Zend_Session::getId()), 'payment')
```

**EDIT: Possible, rather dodgy solution**

I actually managed to restore the session by inserting this to `_initApplication()` in my bootstrap file. It's rather dodgy, so if anyone knows of a better - more ZF'ish - way please advice!

```
    if(isset($_GET[$appConfig->resources->session->name])) {
        session_id($_GET[$appConfig->resources->session->name]);
    }
```

**EDIT: DOH!**

Well.. turns out previous edit is not needed. Just before i added the previous lines to the bootstrap i also changed the url layout.

Changed it from `/pay/UPSSESSID/{session-id-here}` to `/pay?UPSSESSID={session-id-here}` - And that was actually the root of the problem :(

Now i have removed the lines from the bootstrap and the sessionId i restored correctly.

My mistake!

Comment: I assume _wan't_ is _want_ and not a combination/typo of _don't want_ ?

Comment: I think you might get more response if you explain why you *need* to do this...I'm not sure if you do really do understand the security implications of this.

Comment: I do understand the security implications of this, actually wrote it in my first paragraph. I need this to secure that the user session don't get lost in the redirects between servers. Once the user clicks 'I want to pay with creditcard' - The user is directed to the (PG) payment-gateway company's webserver that proxies the creditcard-form-page from my server. The form in cc-form-page submits to another page on the PG-server with added OK-URL and fail-URL as parameters....

Comment: ... If the CC checksout OK, the user is directed to OK-URL on my server which finishes the order as 'is payed'. Thus the OK-URL and fail-URL also needs the SessionID, so the user is still logged in after she finishes the payment.

Comment: AND all this is due to some rules in Denmark, that basicly denies use of creditcard forms on shop-servers, not even if they got SSL. All input and requests countaining CC-data should go to through authorized payment gateways and their SSL. In the end this is to protect consumers.

I could use a payment window, but it would give all other kinds of problems - popup blockers etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPSESSID can not - by default - be passed as part of a URL-rewrite.

`?PHPSESSID={session_id}`-format solved my problem.